# MVP vs. Event driven in android applications

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, architecture

I assume you are familiar with MVP and event driven pattern.
Both of MVP and Event driven patterns, to my knowledge, are designed to separate responsibly and increase readability. But using libraries like Event bus makes achieving event driven easier.

My question is that given you can separate your methods responsibilities using event and subscriber pattern, what is the benefit of changing your application architecture to MVP?

And second part of my question is the feasibility of using an event library(like Eventbus) along with MVP pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Event-driven architecture is for communication. You use it to transmit messages/events among loosely coupled components in your app. **Benefit**: you get rid of the headache of adding/removing components, i.e removing subscribers without modifying publishers an so forth.

MVP is for structuring application logic. It helps you keep business logic far away from GUI and introduces Presenter as a middle-man handling events on View, involving appropriate Model to proceed business logic corresponding to every View's event, and formatting data to the View. **Benefit**: It draws the boundaries between UI logic and Business Logic, allows you to test business logic or even both kinds of logic without any concrete UI stuff.

Now the the first part: As the most concerned is how to compose application logic and how to ensure the logic is well implemented in the application (Unit Testing), MV* can help you, not EventBus.

The second part: Yes you can use EventBus/MessageBus together with MVP as they're responsible for different things. For example, you use MVP to structure a Fragment into View, Presenter and Model and use EventBus/MessageBus to enable communicating between your Fragment and other Activity, Fragment(s) in your app.

An actual framework that provides both MessageBus and MVP is here: http://robo-creative.github.io/mvp. If you want to see how they can be combined along in action, read this guidelines: http://robo-creative.github.io/mvp/presenter-features.html

Comment: ok, to you suggest using MVP or MVC in an android application? Since components are loosely coupled with each other. An activity can act as a controller an meanwhile could be a view( like providing transition animation and so on.)

Comment: MVP is preferred. Activity should not act as Presenter nor Controller. And yes it could be a View.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:  cleaned this up and shortened it.

I don't think the benefits of event driven architecture and MVC architecture are mutually exclusive as your question suggests.  You can design code that is both event driven and consistent with the MVC architecture.

Event driven means you have event handlers that execute when certain events occur.  The events start a low level (mouse motions and keyboard motions) and percolate up through the tool kit to your higher level handlers.   MVC is concerned how you organize the the location of the handlers and how they interface with the business logic.

So getting back to EventBus.   If you are pointing all your UI events through the EventBus, and all changes to the Model are in turn passed through Eventbus back to the View, then I would say the EventBus library makes up a significant part of the Controller in your MVC architecture.

When I think about MVC, my goal is to decouple business logic and data from the presentation of the data.  Something like Eventbus can help you do that.  You controller class is going to tie your model the EventBus, and plug the UI into the other side.  When your done, your model only knows that it was given an event stream.  It doesn't know if event stream is fed by a GUI, a piece of test apparatus, or a hardware debugger.

Comment: I've used Event driven code in my apps for a while. And really agree with you that event driven code acts like a MVC pattern where a view doesn't know where the answer came from it just fires an event. But my question is in your second assertion that an event driven architecture can be replace with a MVC pattern. do you think that if use event bus (for eg.) then I wouldn't need to use MVP pattern in my app?

Comment: I didn't mean to say Event driven replaces MVC.  It can be used in conjunction with MVC. Perhaps I misunderstood what you mean by Event Driven.  To me that means, low level events (timer overflows, or button clicks from the user) percolate up to higher layers including the business logic. High level code can't predict/control the order of operations.  Indeed some operations may execute simultaneously in different threads.   The opposite would be some kind of polling loop.  There, timer & button states are checked repeatedly, until something happens, and then the loop calls the handler.

Comment: I was just discussing this with someone and he things I might still misunderstand you.  Do you mean to suggest that using the Event bus makes your program "Not event driven"?   Or Not MVP?   It is hard to find a UI tool kit anywhere that is not event driven.  And EventBus goes a long way (not all the way) to hiding the View from the Model.    So which benefit do you think you are not getting?  And Why?